# I am having an issue loading the Icon library from react-native-elements

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I am unable to use the Icon component from react-native-vector-icons.  I was able to use it before with no issues, but now when I import the Icon component into my App.js file that I created with Expo, I get an error.

I have already uninstalled and reinstalled Expo, uninstalled and reinstalled react-native-elements, and created a new Expo project.

Here is my App.js file from Expo.  The only thing that is changed from the default App.js file is the import of the Icon and the Button components.  The Button component renders correctly.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Icon, Button } from 'react-native-elements';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <Button title='hello' />
      <Icon
        name='g-translate'
        color='#00aced' 
        />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

And here is my package.json:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^33.0.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I get the error [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Directory for file:///Users/{myusername}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CE65DD4F-AFFE-46F7-A173-6B25AF30CBCE/data/Containers/Data/Application/DB21F77C-3BE4-470E-AA62-52E6C8376F0C/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540psoren%252FOctave/ExponentAsset-b06871f281fee6b241d60582ae9369b9.ttf doesn't exist.]
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js:155:41 in createErrorFromErrorData
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules.js:104:55 in